# VanillaJS - change event fires twice

Tags: javascript

I am writing an app for a client and hit a wall. At the beggining of an app I have one element on page which includes 2 buttons - copy and delete. Copy copies as many times as user put in input field, delete button deletes selected segment. I'm using event delegation to add button functions for copied elements and `MutationObserver` to handle changes in DOM.
This is my `MutationObserver` configuration - `installationContainer` is a container to which we add to or we remove segments from.

```
const targetNode = document.querySelector("#installationContainer");

    const config = {
        childList: true,
        subtree: true,
        attributes: false,
        characterData: false,
    };

    const observer = new MutationObserver(handleDOMChange);
    observer.observe(targetNode, config);
```

```
function handleDOMChange(mutations) {
    const segments = document.querySelectorAll('.installationSegment');
    segments.forEach((segment, i) => {
        segment.addEventListener('change', e => {
            handleInputAndSelectChange(e, segments, i);
        }, false)
    });
    systemInformation();
}
```

Whenever I add segments everything works perfectly, for every segment there is checkbox, 2 selects. Selecting all checkboxes and changing data ( in selects or input ) changes data for segments, that's perfect, but unfortunatelly my problems occurs when I delete some segments using button for it, changes are detected by `MutationObserver` and segments is deleted from DOM and from array ( array which collects data from all segments in array of objects ). Problem is that when I delete segment or segments and try to change data in some segments located at the bottom of page `change` event fires twice and I can not figure out why this is happening. 
This is my function which handles changes in segment. What is happening here is every time I change something I check if any segment has `checkbox` selected, if so for those segments change data.
**Problem occurs when ever I try to change data for either one segment or multiple segments ( multiple segments I mean segments which have checkbox selected ).** My question is why change event is fired twice in that particular situation ? 
*edited*
When I change data after I add segments to page everything works perfectly.

```
function handleInputAndSelectChange(event, segments, index) {  
    const checkedSegments = selectedCheckboxes(segments) || [];
    switch( event.target.name ) {
        case 'cableSelect': {
            if( checkedSegments.length > 0 ) {
                checkedSegments.forEach((segment) => {
                    const indexToUpdate = Array.from(segments).findIndex(checkedSegment => segment === checkedSegment);
                    const cableSelect = segment.querySelector(`.cableSelect`);
                    cableSelect.value = event.target.value;
                    collectedData[indexToUpdate].cableType = event.target.value;
                });
            } else if( checkedSegments.length === 0 ) {
                collectedData[index].cableType = event.target.value;
            }
            break;
        }

        case 'deviceSelect': {
            if( checkedSegments.length > 0 ) {
                checkedSegments.forEach((segment) => {
                    const indexToUpdate = Array.from(segments).findIndex(checkedSegment => segment === checkedSegment);
                    const deviceSelect = segment.querySelector(`.deviceSelect`);
                    const img = segment.querySelector(`.deviceimage`);

                    chooseImg(img, event.target.value);
                    deviceSelect.value = event.target.value;
                    collectedData[indexToUpdate].deviceType = event.target.value;
                });

            } else if( checkedSegments.length === 0 ) {
                console.log(event);
                console.log(index);
                // console.log(event.currentTarget);
                // const img = document.querySelector(`#deviceimage${index}`);
                // collectedData[index].deviceType = event.target.value;
                // chooseImg(img, event.target.value);
            }
            break;
        }

        case 'cableInput': {
            if( checkedSegments.length > 0 ) {
                checkedSegments.forEach((segment) => {
                    const indexToUpdate = Array.from(segments).findIndex(checkedSegment => segment === checkedSegment);
                    const cableInput = segment.querySelector('input[name="cableInput"]');
                    cableInput.value = event.target.value;
                    collectedData[indexToUpdate].cableLen_m = parseFloat(event.target.value);
                });

            } else if( checkedSegments.length === 0 ) {

                // collectedData[indexToUpdate].cableLen_m = parseFloat(event.target.value);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you make a simulation e. g. on https://jsfiddle.net? I guess addEventListener is attached twice somehow.

Comment: @j0ste hey, thanks for your response. I don't think I can because everything I do there is made in pure JS - dom manipulation, creating elements, segments etc, I can give however link to github with this app and give you instructions how to call out this "error".

Comment: @j0ste I thought so as well, but the problem is that If addEventListener is attached twice after every change I would invoke this change twice, not only in situation when I delete segment and try to change data in segment located at the bottom of list.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: @j0ste Prefer asking for a [Stack Snippet](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269753/3982562) over JSFiddle.

Comment: @ThomasSablik minimal reproducible example means that I give you whole app to be honest, In my answer below I wrote why in my opinion my problem occurs, and I think it's that, becouse amount of dom changes = amount of change events fired

Comment: [mcve] means that you create a small example that reproduces the problem. Most of your code can be reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

All right, so I think I figure it out. I belive, that described problem occurs because of `handleDOMChange` function. In this function I am selecting all segments and to every segment I apply `eventListener`. So every time I do changes in DOM ( adding segment or removing it ) I reapply `evertListener` to every segment to listen for changes, so when I add segments once `eventListener` fires one, when I do many manipulations on DOM, the amount of manipulations is equal to amount of new eventListeners attached to segment.